# Restrict apply CSS property on a particular tag which is present in div tag

Tags: html, css

For eg.
I don't want that the CSS property should not be applied on the h4 tag

```css
.abc {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
<h4>Hello 1</h4>
<p>Hello 2</p>
<p>Hello 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Double negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [:not pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```css
.abc :not(h4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
<h4>Hello 1</h4>
<p>Hello 2</p>
<p>Hello 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan